# Building native app with ffmpeg lib

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I have created libffmpeg.so using the android build system. Now I'm trying to use in my app. Pls help me with following questions:

1. How do I add ffmpeg to my includes directory?
2. How do I link to ffmpeg.so?

Thanks,
Nahum

---

Well I did at written, getting the following error:
`1.7.9(0.237/5/3)
Prebuilt       : libffmpeg.so <=
cp: omitting directory`/cygdrive/c/android2/android-ndk-r6/samples/native-audio
/jni'
make: *** [/cygdrive/c/android2/android-ndk-r6/samples/native-audio/obj/local/ar
meabi/libffmpeg.so] Error 1`

Please advice.
Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was, more or less, following this 
http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-android-applications-based-on-ffmpeg-by-an-example/
and also here on Stack Overflow there's a lote of similar answers

Basically linking an FFMPEG libs is no different from linking any other SOs. You can read in NDK/docs

Comment: Why do I need the sources under jni? I tried putting them under usr/include and got more errors.

Comment: You do not really need all the sources under jni but you definitely will need header files and so they are placing everything under jni. It might be possible to tell your Android.mk to look up headers in a different place but normally everything native goes under the jni folder.